# Selecting time dimension for a given latitude and longitude from an Xarray dataset

Tags: indexing, python-xarray

I am looking for suggestion on the fastest way to select a time-series for a given latitude and longitude from an xarray dataset. xarray dataset that I am working with is 3 dimensional of the shape [400, 2000, 7200] where the first dimension is time (400), then latitude (2000) and longitude (7200). I simply need to read in individual time-series for each of the grid cells in a given rectangle. So I am reading in time-series one by one for each grid cell with the given rectangle.

For this selection I am using .sel option.

XR..sel(latitude=Y, longitude=X)

Where XR is a xarray dataset, and Y and X are the given latitude and longitude.

This works well but turns about to be very slow when repeated several times. Is there a faster option to do this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: how are the values in your dataset stored? Are you reading this dataset from a netcdf file, are they dask arrays? Also, what version of xarray are you using.

Comment: The values are stored as a three dimension array [time, lat, long]. Yes I am reading the data from a netcdf file using the open_dataset command, in fact the netcdf file that I am reading was written using the xarray's to_netcdf option. xarray version: 0.10.0.  I haven't defined chunk size.  Thanks!